# Get first word after a pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm new to regex and I'm struggling with this scenario, given this string:

```
'<Setting Attribute="AbsencePeriod" SortOrder="Descending"/>'
```

I would like to extract the attribute name like this:

```
AbsencePeriod
```

I wonder what is the regex pattern to achieve this result.

Nb: I know I could parse the xml but I want to avoid that

Comment: `/Attribute="([a-zA-Z]+)"/` https://jsfiddle.net/dkou2m7r/ but as Shubham said is it better to use

Comment: Why do you want to use a regex here, Also the data you provided seems like JSX component

Comment: It's xml and comes as a string, I wanted to avoid to parse the xml

Comment: Thank you @zebnat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the better way to extract your attribute is to parse it with an XML Parser.

But if you really want to use regex and with Javascript, use regex :  `/Attribute="([a-zA-Z]+)"/`

Like this :

```js
    var s = '<Setting Attribute="AbsencePeriod" SortOrder="Descending"/>';
    var matches = s.match(/Attribute="([a-zA-Z]+)"/);
    console.log(matches[1]); // "AbsencePeriod"
```